# What is "slatwall shelving" in Japanese?

Tags: words

I would like to ask a general contractor to make me some [slatwall shelving](http://www.crowndisplay.co.uk/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_33&products_id=210).

I checked dictionaries and all the Google juice I could muster but couldn't figure out what this type of shelving is called in Japanese.

Can anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common term would be 「スラットウォール棚{だな}」.

「スラットウォール什器{じゅうき}」 is also used, but it is not as common.

This is what you get if you image-search 「スラットウォール棚」.

http://image.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=&p=%E2%80%9D%E3%82%B9%E3%83%A9%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A9%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AB%E6%A3%9A%E2%80%9D